# C# crm linQ LinkEntities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to query from a `CRM entity` some values where a `linked entity` contains a `string` inside its `name`.

I try to explain:

- I have `new_supplycontract` table.
- This table, has an `EntityReference` named `new_pod`
- The `new_pod` entity, has two fields: new_citypod and `new_street`
- `new_citypod` points to another entity named `new_city`
- `new_street` points to another entity named `new_street`

I need to query the `new_supplycontract` table to retrieve only the records whose `new_pod` contains a `street` which name contains a `string` I pass and a `city` which name contains another `string` i pass.

I know this code works for retrieving all `new_supplycontract` entities whose two text fields "`new_city`" and "`new_address`" are like to two strings passed.

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(new_supplycontract.EntityLogicalName);
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
query.Criteria.AddCondition("new_city", ConditionOperator.NotNull);
query.Criteria.AddCondition("new_address", ConditionOperator.NotNull);

query.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity(new_supplycontract.EntityLogicalName, "new_comune", "new_city", "new_comuneid", JoinOperator.Inner)); 
query.LinkEntities[0].Columns.AddColumns("new_name");
query.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "comuneTemp";
query.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("new_name", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" + comune + "%");

query.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity(new_supplycontract.EntityLogicalName, new_via.EntityLogicalName, "new_address", "new_viaid", JoinOperator.Inner));
query.LinkEntities[1].Columns.AddColumns("new_name");
query.LinkEntities[1].EntityAlias = "viaTemp";
query.LinkEntities[1].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("new_name", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" + via + "%");


DataCollection<Entity> entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;
```

But I don't really know how to use this code for my goal. I don't know how to filter an entityreference's entityreference.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: put this: new LinkEntity(new_supplycontract.EntityLogicalName, "new_comune", "new_city", "new_comuneid", JoinOperator.Inner); in a new variable. Then, you can add a link entity to that variable the same way you are doing here with query. That's how you chain them.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedEntities can have nested LinkedEntities in CRM 2011. This was changed since 2013 where an EntityName attribute was introduced and there wasn't a need for having nested entities.

But basically, you could start from the supplycontract entity, then add a linked entity against your new_pod entity. From that Linked Entity, you'll need to add 2 linked entities, one to the new_city entity  and another one to the new_street entity. Each of these 2 linked entities will need a contains condition expression where you pass the 2 strings you want to use for filtering.

Ex:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(new_supplycontract.EntityLogicalName);
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
var le = query.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity(new_pod.EntityLogicalName, "new_pod", "new_pod", "new_podid", JoinOperator.Inner)); 

var lePod = le.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity(new_pod.EntityLogicalName, "new_city", "new_citypod", "new_cityid", JoinOperator.Inner));
var leCity = le.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity(new_pod.EntityLogicalName, "new_street", "new_street", "new_streetid", JoinOperator.Inner));

//Add conditions to each nested linked entity now as above.
```

Now, I personally prefer LINQ cause the query is much more easier to read than using LinkedEntities.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! just a question: you used `var le = ..` but the `linkEntities.Add` is` void`. After you used `le.Linkentities.add ...` but I have to use everywhere `query.linkedentities.add...,` instead, right?

Comment: btw, just to know, I knew with linQ the "like" operator was not working on CRM, I tried it some weeks ago but without any success, is there a way to make it working?

Comment: Did you try .Contains("string")? Or alternatively .StartsWith("string") or .EndsWith("string"). .Contains might break the index and be really bad from a performance point of view unless using FULL TEXT indexes

Comment: Yeah i tried them all, but they doesn't work.. starts and endswith are not good for my program, the perfect one would be "contains" but it doesn't works unfortunatly

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into countless issues with LINQ to CRM, mostly due to my misunderstanding of how it works.  Unfortunately, Query Expressions are extremely verbose and hard to read.  I created and use the DLaB.Xrm library to make my life simpler (and more typed, I love me some EarlyBound Dev)

Here is your query using DLaB.Xrm:

```
var qe = QueryExpressionFactory.Create<new_supplycontract>();
var podLink = qe.AddLink<new_pod>(new_supplycontract.Fields.new_Pod, new_pod.Fields.Id);

podLink.AddLink<new_city>(new_pod.Fields.new_citypod,              // This is the attribute of the "from" entity to join on
                          new_city.Fields.Id,                      // This is the attribute of the "to" entity to join on.  If name is identical, this parameter can be removed
                          new ColumnSet(new_city.Fields.new_name)) // AliasedValue to add to the result
    .LinkCriteria.AddCondition("new_name", ConditionOperator.Like, "%" + comune + "%");

podLink.AddLink<new_street>(new_pod.Fields.new_street, 
                            new_street.Fields.Id,
                            ColumnSet(new_street.Fields.new_name))
    .LinkCriteria.AddCondition("new_name", ConditionOperator.Like,  "%" + via + "%");

var leads = service.GetEntities(qe);
```

Comment: That is fantastic! just a question, trying to install the nuget package gives me an error: Could not install package 'DLaB.Common 1.0.1.13'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.  I could install the 1.0.0 version, but all other versions give me this error, I missed something?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley I think you have to target 4.5.2.

Comment: Why not?  it's an in place upgrade? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/07/moving-to-the-net-framework-4-5-2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain the link entities. Here's an example:

```
        ConditionExpression condition3 = new ConditionExpression();
        ...
        LinkEntity link3 = new LinkEntity();
        ...
        link3.LinkCriteria.Conditions.Add(condition3);

        ConditionExpression condition2 = new ConditionExpression();
        ...
        LinkEntity link2 = new LinkEntity();
        ...
        link2.LinkCriteria.Conditions.Add(condition2);

        LinkEntity link1 = new LinkEntity();
        ...
        link1.LinkEntities.Add(link2);
        link1.LinkEntities.Add(link3);

        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("");
        ...
        query.LinkEntities.Add(link1);

        DataCollection<Entity> entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;
```

It helps to write them separately and use .Criteria.Conditions.Add() instead of .Criteria.AddCondition()